# Table in LaTeX with tcolorbox-tabularx, how to get spacing correct

Tags: tables, tabularx, tcolorbox, arrays

I want to create a good looking table in LaTeX and found tcolorbox quite useful. However the spacing in the table seems off as I want items to be evenly spaced and not going outside of the table. In particular there is some times too much space between items and sometimes too little. And in particular no space is left towards the right hand side. How can I change this?

My code is:

```
\usepackage[usenames,dvipsnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{colortbl}
\tcbuselibrary{skins}

\newcolumntype{Y}{>{\raggedleft\arraybackslash}X}



\tcbset{tab2/.style={enhanced,fonttitle=\bfseries,fontupper=\normalsize\sffamily,
colback=white!10!white,colframe=blue!50!black,colbacktitle=blue!40!white,
coltitle=black,center title}}


\begin{tcolorbox}[tab2,tabularx={X||YYYYYYYY},title=Objects,boxrule=0.5pt]

$d=2$ & $Z^{:2:}$ & $Z^{:3:}$ &  \multicolumn{4}{Y}{} \\ \hline
$d=3$ & $Z^{:2:}$ & $Z^{:3:}$ & $ZY$ & $ZY^2$ & $Z^{:2:}Y$ & $Z^{:2:}\tL^{-1}(Z^2)$\\ 

\end{tcolorbox}
```

Comment: Please tell us which document class you employ and hor (or where) `\tL` is defined.

Comment: Sure. I am employing \documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{article} and I define \tL as \newcommand{\tL}{\tilde{\mathcal L}}

Comment: As  `tcolorbox` doesn't seem to be compatible with the  `>{\hsize=x\hsize}` constructs, the only solution I see would be to load `geometry`to have different margins. B.t.x=w., your code declares more columns than the number of actually used columns.

Comment: The output of `{
\setlength{\tabcolsep}{12pt}
\begin{tcolorbox}[tab2,tabularx={X||*{6}{r}},title=Objects,boxrule=0.5pt]
$d=2$ & $Z^{:2:}$ & $Z^{:3:}$ &  \multicolumn{4}{Y}{} \\ \hline
$d=3$ & $Z^{:2:}$ & $Z^{:3:}$ & $ZY$ & $ZY^2$ & $Z^{:2:}Y$ & $Z^{:2:}\tL^{-1}(Z^2)$\\ 
\end{tcolorbox}
}` is probably closer to the expected one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that the table has 7, not 9, columns overall. Changing `tabularx={X||YYYYYYYY}` to `tabularx={X||YYYYYc}` should do the trick, especially if one defines `Y` to center rather than right-align its contents.

A further refinement, not applied below, might be to execute `\addtolength{\tabcolsep}{4pt}`.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[usenames,dvipsnames,table]{xcolor}

\usepackage{tabularx}
\newcolumntype{Y}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}X}

\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\tcbuselibrary{skins}
\tcbset{tab2/.style={enhanced,fonttitle=\bfseries,
   fontupper=\normalsize\sffamily,colback=white!10!white,
   colframe=blue!50!black,colbacktitle=blue!40!white,
   coltitle=black,center title}}
   
\newcommand{\tL}{\tilde{\mathcal{L}}}

\begin{document}

\begin{tcolorbox}[tab2,tabularx={Y||YYYYYc},title=Objects,boxrule=0.5pt]
$d=2$ & $Z^{:2:}$ & $Z^{:3^{\mathstrut}:}$  \\ 
\hline
$d=3$ & $Z^{:2:}$ & $Z^{:3^{\mathstrut}:}$ & $ZY$ & $ZY^2$ & $Z^{:2:}Y$ & $Z^{:2:}{\tL}^{-1}(Z^2)$\\ 
\end{tcolorbox}

\end{document}
```